# htaccess rewrite exclusion not working

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

I have an issue that I have been struggling on for hours now. I can't seem to get this to work how I want it too. Simply put, I want to redirect all url requests to www.test.com.au except for those from the IP addresses below or any request the has "/unsubscribe/" in the URL.

The IP address exclusions work perfectly. However, trying to reach for example www.test.com.au/flashsale/newsletter/subscriber/unsubscribe/id/8255/code/7iji5wv5hs8e3klvwwltlqy2bjmpmg5f/ redirects back to / everytime and I do not want it to.

Here is my broken rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^110\.174\.129\.147
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^203\.217\.17\.162
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.67\.4\.233
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/unsubscribe/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* / [R=301,L]
```

Where am I going wrong?

PS: this is killing me.

Comment: Weird indeed. Have you tried using the full URI, up until `id` in your condition? Alternatively, the entire URI with the necessary wildcards?

Comment: I have modified this line a few time now, including the following: `!^/flashsale/newsletter/subscriber/unsubscribe(.)* [NC]` with no luck. @MikeAnthony

Comment: I am quite positive that this rule is causing all the issues as when I remove it completely the URL hits fine.

Comment: It's not `(.)*`, it's `(.*)` for 0 or more characters, or `(.+)` for 1 or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file should look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/flashsale/newsletter/subscriber/unsubscribe/id/[\d]+/code/[a-z\d]+/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^110\.174\.129\.147 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^203\.217\.17\.162 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.67\.4\.233 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

**Explanation:**

1. The first change is the addition of the `OR` flag. Your original code did not have this. `mod_rewrite` will automatically assume the `AND` flag, which meant that your code was checking for all IP addresses.
2. The second change involved fully specifying the full `REQUEST_URI` to check, with the necessary wild cards. The first wild card (`\d`) checks for digits, whilst the second one (`a-z\d`) checks for both digits and characters from 'a' to 'z'.

**Edits:**

I have now also made an edit. I have moved the `unsubscribe` part to the top. This will ensure that the request does not match the given string, AND that ANY of the listed IP addresses are not being used to access the request.

(Please note that I am not in a testing environment at the moment. My modifications are not guaranteed to work.)

Comment: thanks for the quick response mike, but the above code still doesn't work for me. The rule is still re-directing to `/`. I'm still very new to .htaccess and regex, what exactly does you modification say?

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and restart your browser. Then try replacing your code with following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(110\.174\.129\.147|203\.217\.17\.162|111\.67\.4\.233)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/unsubscribe/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Sorry, this breaks the IP exceptions, do you possibly know why?

Comment: Weird, for which IP did this rule break?

Comment: The site is supposed to be inaccessible except for requests going to the listed IP's and any URI that has the string unsubscribe in it. When I tested the site through a proxy, it loaded, which means requests were not being re-directed back to `/`

Comment: I have already tested this code. May I know what was your URL when you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this extension. It might not solve your problem completely, but its worth a try.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/optimise-web-mass-301-redirects-1589.html

Comment: Sorry Shatir but I need a .htaccess solution to this as the rule is already defined. The exception for unsubscribe is a new modification.